# Endpoint /crx/packmgr/installstatus.jsp in AEM always returns 1

Tags: aem, aem-6

On some of our AEM instances, the endpoint /crx/packmgr/installstatus.jsp always returns

```
{
    "status": {
        "finished": false,
        "itemCount": 1
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas why could it happen or ways to debug this issue?

Comment: Can you post the full `curl` or script that you are using? Is the package too big? If you install the package manually, how long it takes?

Comment: I am just doing get query using browser like this
hostname:4502/crx/packmgr/installstatus.jsp
and it always returns json which I posted in question. Even after a day after last deployment. The instance overall works correctly apart of this.

Comment: I understand now, I would try filtering the packages and see if there is a package that seems to be installed but it didn't finish correctly, to figure it out, the last installed message will be empty for that package, that is, no time will be shown. I have seen that before.

Comment: did we get a solution to this? We are seeing this in our lower environments.

Comment: Also having this on some (lower) environments but no idea why.  Would be nice if someone know _how_ to check which package is the offending one.